# `dotMemoryUnit` with `dotnet test`

Tags: .net-core, xunit, dotmemory

I typically run my unit tests using `dotnet test`. The framework I'm using is `xunit`. As such, I'm not sure how to run dotMemory unit tests with the CLI.

The documentation recommends:

```
dotMemoryUnit.exe
-targetExecutable="C:\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe"
-returnTargetExitCode --"E:\MyProject\bin\Release\MainTests.dll"
```

What should I put in `-targetExecutable`? It expects a path, so entering `dotnet test` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to run tests using latest dotMemory Unit 3.1, it works

`dotMemoryUnit.exe "c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -- test "path\to\the\solution.sln"`

For your version it would be

`dotMemoryUnit.exe -targetExecutable="c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
-returnTargetExitCode -- test "E:\MyProject\bin\Release\MainTests.dll"`